# Batch script: Search if a folder contains any files

Tags: search, file, batch-file, directory

I am trying to get a batch script to check whether a folder contains any files in it. So far this is how far I have got:

```
IF EXIST %FILEPATH%\%%i\FromGlobus\%FILE% (

%WINZIP% %FILEPATH%\GlobusEOD\ExtraFiles\%ZIPFILE% -m %FILE%
IF errorlevel 1 goto subBADEND

)
```

where `%FILE%` is `*.*` but what happens is it tries to zip up files even when none exist and therefore fails!

Any tips or ideas?

Thank you

Comment: All solutions seem to requiring running `dir`. The problem with this is that it can take a while if the target folder contains a lot of files/subdirectories.

Answer (score 2):

After some tinkering with my own scripts

A variation of [@Belisarius'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922200/batch-script-search-if-a-folder-contains-any-files/3927826#3927826) answer is what I've been using for awhile...After tinkering for a bit, [@NimeCloud's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922200/batch-script-search-if-a-folder-contains-any-files/7817601#7817601) version just doesn't seem to work on my XP machine...

I've come up with a blend of the two that seems to work for my needs:

```
%FOLDER%=C:\Temp
FOR /F %%i in ('dir /b "%FOLDER%\*.*"') DO ( goto :Process )
goto :Exit

:Process
...
...
...

:Exit
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use something like

```
set VAR=init
for /f %%a in ('dir /b c:\kk\*.*') do set VAR=exists
if %VAR%==exists ...
```

Not very efficient in case of large directories, but it works.

HTH!

Comment: I've used this in batch files... Depending on if @NimeCloud answer works or not, this does work. I think Nimes is more 'graceful'.

Comment: There's no need to loop through all the results, you can break out of the loop after the first one using labels like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13601015/how-can-i-get-the-first-line-of-the-output-for-given-command-in-dos/13601429#13601429

Answer (score 1):

dir *.* returns .  .. maybe these virtual dirs cause the mess. You could try FIND pipe like below:

```
SET filter=*.*
SET notfound="File not found"

DIR %filter% | FIND %notfound% 
@If ErrorLevel 1 Goto :end
```

Comment: I like this answer... little easier to follow than @Belisarius answer IMO.

Comment: If there is a file named "File not found" this script fails :)

Comment: It also fails for `*.*` because `dir *.*` always returns something for all directories, including empty directories, for which it returns `.` and `..` (it returns nothing with the `/b` switch, but that still won’t work since this script is looking for the `File not found` error which is still not returned).

Answer (score 1):

If you use `/A:-D` for `dir` command, then it will switch the return code if directory has files. Works only for files (`/A:D` won't work for subdirectories in the same way)

`dir /A:-D /B "mydir" >nul 2>nul && echo.mydir having files`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `find` with `dir` to ensure the return code matches what you'd expect when no files are found:

```
DIR /A /B | >NUL FIND /V "" && ECHO Folder contains files || ECHO Folder empty
```