# Look for certain file within subdirectories if found do nothing. If not found run command

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I am looking for a way to run a batch file and find a file within subdirectories. If the file is found just exit but if its not found go ahead and run command. This is what I have so far but it doesnt look through subdirectories.

```
timeout /t 30
IF EXIST Z:\K\Downloads\*.tmp (
echo Nope
exit
) ELSE (
psexec \\192.168.2.120 -h -u Filebot -p password -i -s "K:/Downloads/Filebot/FilebotMedia.bat"
)
```

Comment: Try dir z:\file /S /b and check the output

Comment: I tried that and it doesnt execute the ) ELSE (

Comment: Show what _exactly_ you tried

Comment: timeout /t 30
IF EXIST dir Z:\K\Downloads\*.tmp /S /b (
echo Nope
exit
) ELSE (
psexec \\192.168.2.120 -h -u Filebot -p password -i -s "K:/Downloads/Filebot/FilebotMedia.bat"
)

Comment: This is syntactically incorrect. Use Dir alone and.combine this with findstr or find. Or change your current code along this:http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html

Comment: If I use dir "Z:\K\Downloads\*.tmp" by itself I am able to find the files. But then how am I able to execute another command if they are found or if they are not, else, do something else? Sorry I am a bit confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
timeout /t 30
>nul 2>nul dir /a-d /s "Z:\K\Downloads\*.tmp" && (
  echo Nope
  exit
) || (
  psexec \\192.168.2.120 -h -u Filebot -p password -i -s "K:/Downloads/Filebot/FilebotMedia.bat"
)
pause
```

The basis of this is found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10818854/5022761), but edited so it only works for your specific extension.

Please note that users won't be able to see what you echo as you have no pause after your echo.