# How to check if SEVERAL folders are empty in loop in batch?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to check if several folders are empty in batch. By empty, I mean "has no files".
I am passing each folder to a separate script. Seems like it has a syntax issue. 
Could you provide help please ? Thanks ! 
Please note that I am looking at SEVERAL FOLDERS, ONE BY ONE. Thanks!

Script CopyFiles.bat

```
for /F %%i in ('dir /b %~1*.*') do (
   echo Folder is NON empty
 )
echo Folder is empty or does not exist
```

Main Script :

```
@echo off

for /F %%i in ('dir /b C:\*.*') do 
(
    call CopyFiles.bat %%i
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if any type of files exist in a directory using BATCH script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813943/check-if-any-type-of-files-exist-in-a-directory-using-batch-script)

Comment: There *is* a syntax issue - in `Main`, the `(` following the `do` **must** be on the same physical line as the `do`. You should specify what happens for you, since we can't see over your shoulder and it may behave differently on others' machines. There *are* other issues, but following the myriad examples of how to approach your (unstated) aim available on SO should lead you to a solution.

Comment: Thanks @Magoo  What I am trying to do is to go through all the folders in C and check one by one if there are empty. In C, I have a succession of folders : User1, User2, User3 , etc. And I want to know which one is empty, which one is not. Let me know if you have any ideas . Thank you !

Comment: Depends on **Your** definition of `empty`. Do you mean 'has no files` or `has no subdirectories` or `has neither files nor subdirectories`? All of this data should be provided by editing it into the question (edit button) as we don't assemble data from comments (usually) - all of the relevant data in one place, please! (and follow Squishman's link, which will provide relevant clues)

Comment: Thanks again @Magoo. I edited the question accordingly. I meant ":has no files" by empty. Also, Squishman's link solves the issue for only one folder, and not several folders as I need. Thanks.

Comment: @LouInNY, if you understand the code from the link I posted, you can adapt that to your needs.  Pretty sure the i on the keyboard is nowhere near the a.

Comment: Thanks Squashman. U mean something along those lines  ? I am not really good at batch files  .. :

@echo off

for /F %%i in ('dir /b C:\*.*') do 
(
 dir /a-d "%%i\*" && (echo Files exist) || (echo No file found)
)

Comment: I got it to work ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to loop on the folders and use the "dir /a-d" command as suggested by Squashman :

```
 @echo off

 for /F %%i in ('dir /b "C:\*.*"') do (
    echo C:\%%i
    dir /a-d "C:\%%i\*" && (echo Files exist) || (echo No file found)
 )
 pause
```

Comment: As written, this won't work for folders with spaces or ampersands. You're also processing files without the /ad switch. I would suggest changing the FOR /F to `FOR /D %%i IN (C:\*) DO (`

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
@WHERE /Q "%~1:*"&&(@ECHO=Has files&@TIMEOUT 4)||(@ECHO=Has no files&@TIMEOUT 4)
```