# CMD: Checking if a specific file is absent in a specific folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd, path, directory

How would I be able to check if a folder was missing a specific file? I assume it would be some combination of `if not exist X (execute Y)` and the path name, but I haven't been able to come up with any solutions.

From `if /?`

```
EXIST filename      Specifies a true condition if the specified filename exists.
```

Not sure where I would put the path to the folder.

Essentially what I'm asking is how would I [Check if any type of files exist in a directory using BATCH script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813943/check-if-any-type-of-files-exist-in-a-directory-using-batch-script), but only a specific filename in a specific folder? (And then place a `not` in front)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To safely check for a file, use this (based on the [`dir`](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) command and [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)):

```
> nul 2>&1 dir /A:-D "D:\path\to\folder\file.ext" || echo File is missing!
```

To check for a folder, you could use this:

```
> nul 2>&1 dir /A:D "D:\path\to\folder" || echo Folder is missing!
```

---

For the sake of completeness:

To check for a folder, append a trailing `\`to the path, like

```
if not exist "D:\path\to\folder\" echo Folder is missing!
```

To check for a specific file in that folder, the following is not secure...:

```
if not exist "D:\path\to\folder\file.ext" echo File is missing!
```

..., because this would `not` match a folder named `file.ext` also.

Answer (score 1):

```
if not exist "d:\path to\filename.ext" (dothis)
```

If I understand your purpose correctly.