# .bat script to search all folders for a specific temp subfolder

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a set of folders that looks like this:

Folder1

Folder2

Folder3

I need to search each folder & verify that there's NOT a subfolder called temp in it it.  If there's a temp folder in there, that means there was an error.

If a temp folder is found, I'd like to have a .txt file created that lists each main folder that has a temp folder.  Example of the failed.txt file:

Folder2 failed

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Quick and dirty `dir /ad /s /b temp>failed.txt`

Comment: Awesome!  That gets me halfway there.  What do I need to add if I also want to check if any of the Folders are completely empty?

Comment: Please be more specific. Which folders do you want to check for being empty? The root folders or the temp folder?  Going forward do not change the scope of your question.

Comment: Check root folder as well.  So, if Folder1 is empty or has a temp folder, write to the text file.

Comment: By empty do you mean no files and no sub folders?

Comment: Correct.  No files or sub folders.

Comment: What have you tried on your own so far?

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: dir /ad /s /b temp>failed.txt
    dir /ad /s /b 2>nul>emtpy3.txt
    for /d /r %1 %%A in (.) do (
      dir /a /b "%%~fA" 2>nul | findstr "^" >nul || echo %%~fA
    ) > empty2.txt

Comment: To check if no files or folders exist in a directory you can use @dbenham 's code at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10818854/1417694)

Answer (score 0):

Squashman's hint is close: next command searches for `temp` subfolder recursively, starting in current directory `.\`

```
>failed.txt dir /ad /s /b .\temp* | findstr /I /R "\\temp$"
```