# How can i get the first line of the output for given command in dos

Tags: dos

I need to get the very first line of the command line output not all line, For example if i give

```
             C:\Temp> dir
```

I need display the Very first line only like,

```
             11/15/2012  06:58 PM    <DIR>          .
```

How can i get this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not the first line of output from the `dir` command. You would normally get something like `Volume in drive C has no label.` Please explain *precisely* what you want. Is `dir` just an example and you want to be able to get the first line of any command, or do you want to get the first file/folder from a directory?

Comment: dir /B can be used

Answer (score 19):

One approach to get the first line of output for a given command is to execute the command in a FOR loop, then break out of the loop after the first line.

```
@ECHO OFF

SET COMMAND=dir
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('%COMMAND%') DO (
    SET TEMPVAR=%%A
    GOTO :Print 
)

:Print
ECHO %TEMPVAR%
```

Comment: Best method I've found so far using bare cmd. Thanks ;)