# Head -1 in windows batch file

Tags: windows, head, portable-executable

I'd like to get the first line only from the following command output in windows pe.  See below:

```
wmic nic where "NetConnectionStatus=2" get netconnectionid |findstr /v "^Net"|findstr /v "^$"
```

Select -First would be an option, but it doesn't work. 
I'm not familiar with windows too much I'm familiar with linux.

How could I get only the first line of the output.

If it's possible without findstr even better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i get the first line of the output for given command in dos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13601015/how-can-i-get-the-first-line-of-the-output-for-given-command-in-dos)

Comment: It should work if you can tell me how to insert to the COMMAND the following command:  wmic nic where "NetConnectionStatus=2" get netconnectionid |findstr /v "^Net"|findstr /v "^$", it complains about the | even if I escape it.

Answer (score 0):

How to get the first line is described [here at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13601429/8051589). But you have to escape the `^` and the `|` characters like it's said in [this guide](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php).

The following snipped will work:

```
@echo off

set "command=wmic nic where "netconnectionstatus=2" get netconnectionid ^| findstr /v "^^net" ^| findstr /v "^^$""
echo command: ^<%command%^>

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('%command%') do (
    set tempvar=%%a
    goto :print 
)

:print
echo result: %tempvar%
```

I think the last pipe to `findstr /v "^^$""` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Finally a temporary file can help the best:

```
@echo off
wmic nic where "NetConnectionStatus=2" get netconnectionid |findstr /v "^Net"|findstr /v "^$" >tmp.tmp
set /p etc=<tmp.tmp
echo %etc%
```